# how to fix Missing permissions required

Tags: java, android, xml

I have set all of the required permission in proper manner in manifest file but i don't what i am doing wrong.

[manifest.xml](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f64HSVXS6vjhYeBIcMjA_1HixiYqp8wpHIu3aSkN8Pk/edit?usp=sharing)

Errors I get:

> 1-"Missing permissions required by InterstitialAd.loadAd:
>   android.permission.INTERNET"
>   2-"Missing permissions required by
>   MobileAds.initialize: android.permission.INTERNET" 3-"Missing
>   permissions required by BaseAdView.loadAd:
>   android.permission.INTERNET"

and i get frustrated 
about this error i don't know how to resolve. i have followed all of the solution like invalid cache restart,clean rebuild,set permission etc.. but it didn't worked at all please can someone help me out.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class AnswerPaper extends Activity {

    private View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.but5:
                    Intent mIntent1 = new Intent(AnswerPaper.this, bscitactivity.class);
                    mIntent1.putExtra("file_name", "answers");
                    startActivity(mIntent1);
                    break;
                case R.id.but6:
                    Intent mIntent2 = new Intent(AnswerPaper.this, bscactivity.class);
                   mIntent2.putExtra("file_name", "answers");
                   startActivity(mIntent2);
                    break;
                case R.id.but7:
                      Intent mIntent3 = new Intent(AnswerPaper.this, bscbiotech.class);
                   mIntent3.putExtra("file_name", "answers");
                   startActivity(mIntent3);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionspapers);
        defineButtons();




        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but6);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but7);


        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AnswerPaper.this,pop.class));
            }
        });



        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AnswerPaper.this,pop.class));
            }

        });


    }

    public void defineButtons() {
        findViewById(R.id.but5).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.but6).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.but7).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);


        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-2775391703689141/2346081028");
        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.banner_AdView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change app build.gradle targetSdkVersion to 30 it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

To connect to the internet you have add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml` directly inside `<manifest >` element.

Comment: @Krystian G i did but it didn't worked